# Is it required to encrypt data while transferring over SFTP

Tags: encryption, sftp, public-key-encryption

We are sending some date from one system to another system (outside network). The data will be transferred over SFTP. Some the data is sensitive.

I was told that since we are sending it over SFTP, we don't need to encrypt the data. As per my understanding even if we are sending data over SFTP, we should encrypt it.

I want to know if it's true that we don't need to encrypt data if we are sending over SFTP?

Comment: Do you trust the other system?

Comment: Yes. basically, we will be writing that data to csv files and then copying those csv files to a shared location. Another system (outside the network) wll pick those csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP uses SSH as the underlying protocol.  SSH handles encryption for you.  Provided the SSH connection is secured well (e.g. using a private key) and you trust the system you are communicating with, you don't need to implement any further encryption.

Comment: We will be placing the data (in the form of CSV file) to a shared Box (A secure file sharing system) location. The other system will pick the files from this location.

Comment: Then yes, SFTP provides all the security you need.